# Ansible is not able to fetch all files from remote directory

Tags: ansible

I'm copying log files from remote windows machine to local machine.

This is my Ansible -

```
- name: Debug Msg
  debug: msg="Copying logs at - {{ log_full_path }}"

- name: Debug Msg
  debug: msg="Copying logs from - {{ log_file }}"

- name: Getting directory of files
  win_shell: Get-ChildItem | where {!$_.PsIsContainer} | foreach { $_.Name }
  args:
    chdir: "{{ log_file }}"
  register: files_to_copy

- name: Fetch logs
  fetch: src={{ log_file }} dest={{ log_full_path }} fail_on_missing=yes validate_checksum=yes
  with_items: "{{ files_to_copy.stdout_lines }}"
```

When I run the ansible through my python code, it shows that it's copying files properly but I can't see any file in the destination directory.

```
TASK [Debug Msg] ***************************************************************
ok: [win1] => {
    "msg": "Copying logs at - /tmp/cbl-logs/"
}

TASK [Debug Msg] ***************************************************************
ok: [win1] => {
    "msg": "Copying logs from - C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\log_1557220483.4525"
}

TASK [Getting directory of files] **********************************************
changed: [win1]

TASK [Fetch logs] **************************************************************
ok: [win1] => (item=cbl_debug_1557220483607.cbllog)
ok: [win1] => (item=cbl_error_1557220483610.cbllog)
ok: [win1] => (item=cbl_info_1557220483608.cbllog)
ok: [win1] => (item=cbl_verbose_1557220483608.cbllog)
ok: [win1] => (item=cbl_warning_1557220483609.cbllog)

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
win1                       : ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   

Checking /tmp/cbl-logs/ for copied log files - []
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

according to Ansible [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html) the destination will be like this

```
A directory to save the file into. For example, 
if the dest directory is /backup a src file named /etc/profile 
on host host.example.com, would be saved into /backup/host.example.com/etc/profile
```

so the /tmp/cbl-logs/win1 would be your destination...

Answer (score 0):

so I got the mistake I was making. I was not passing the file name from the iteration to be copied.

After making the below change, I was able to run it

Before:-

```
- name: Fetch logs
  fetch: src={{ log_file }} dest={{ log_full_path }} fail_on_missing=yes validate_checksum=yes
  with_items: "{{ files_to_copy.stdout_lines }}"
```

After:-

```
- name: Fetch logs
  fetch: src={{ log_file }}\{{ item }} dest={{ log_full_path }} fail_on_missing=yes validate_checksum=yes flat=yes
  with_items: "{{ files_to_copy.stdout_lines }}"
```